# flutter : Where is the text File i created

Tags: file, flutter

I wrote an app with flutter which creates a text file, and everything is working well on the emulator and on real device. But I need to open the file on my device and I can't find it. Where am I supposed to look for it ? (I use SM G615F Samsung Galaxy J7 Max)
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for

```
Future<int> readFile() async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile();

    // Read the file.
    String contents = await file.readAsString();

    return contents;
  } catch (e) {
    // If encountering an error, return 0.
    return 0;
  }
}

Future<File> _localFile() async {
    // get the path to the document directory.
    String dir = (await PathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    return new File('$dir/YourFileName.txt');
  }
```

The file would be where ever you wrote it to. The main two directories that you probably would have written it to would be the 

**Temporary directory**
A temporary directory (cache) that the system can clear at any time. On iOS, this corresponds to the NSCachesDirectory. On Android, this is the value that getCacheDir() returns.
**Documents directory**
A directory for the app to store files that only it can access. The system clears the directory only when the app is deleted. On iOS, this corresponds to the NSDocumentDirectory. On Android, this is the AppData directory.
 Take a look at this package I think this might be of interest to you [downloads_path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider).

```
import 'package:downloads_path_provider/downloads_path_provider.dart';  

Future<Directory> downloadsDirectory = DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory;
```

In this code, the downloadsDirectory is the Downloads directory in phone storage, that can be seen by user. Then you can open or email it.